# routingParams.departure has no effect for calculateIsoline

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm using the H.platform.routingService().calculateIsoline method and had expected that the routeParams.departure property would have an effect on the result.
However, changing the date and/or time of day has no effect on the calculated isoline.

In the code below, startLocs is an array of geocode objects with lat and lng

```
let queryDateString = queryDate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');

startLocs.forEach(loc => {
      var routingParams = {
        mode: 'fastest;car;',
        start: `geo!${loc.geocode.lat},${loc.geocode.lng}`,
        range: 600,
        rangetype: 'time',
        departure: queryDateString
      };

      // Define a callback function to process the isoline response.
      var onResult = result => {
        var center = new H.geo.Point(
            result.response.center.latitude,
            result.response.center.longitude
          ),
          isolineCoords = result.response.isoline[0].component[0].shape,
          linestring = new H.geo.LineString(),
          isolinePolygon,
          isolineCenter;

        // Add the returned isoline coordinates to a linestring:
        isolineCoords.forEach(function(coords) {
          linestring.pushLatLngAlt.apply(linestring, coords.split(','));
        });

        // Create a polygon and a marker representing the isoline:
        isolinePolygon = new H.map.Polygon(linestring);
        isolineCenter = new H.map.Marker(center);

        // Add the polygon and marker to the map:
        this.markerGroup.addObject(isolineCenter);
        this.polylineGroup.addObject(isolinePolygon);            
      };

      // Get an instance of the routing service:
      var router = this.platform.getRoutingService();

      // Call the Routing API to calculate an isoline:
      router.calculateIsoline(routingParams, onResult, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      });
    });
    this.isLoading = false;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('failed processing isochrones', err);
  }
```

Regardless of the value of queryDateString in this example, the results are identical.

The documentation states that the ReST APIs query params map to properties in the routeParams so I expected that the departure property should have an effect.  Does anyone know if that's not the case?

EDIT:
Updated to include working example in case anyone stumbles across this:

```
let queryDateString = queryDate.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss');
let onResult = result => {

      let center = new H.geo.Point(
        result.response.center.latitude,
        result.response.center.longitude
      )

      let isolineCoords = result.response.isoline[0].component[0].shape;
      let linestring = new H.geo.LineString();
      let isolinePolygon;
      let isolineCenter;

      // Add the returned isoline coordinates to a linestring:
      isolineCoords.forEach(function(coords) {
        linestring.pushLatLngAlt.apply(linestring, coords.split(','));
      });

      // Create a polygon and a marker representing the isoline:
      isolinePolygon = new H.map.Polygon(linestring);
      isolineCenter = new H.map.Marker(center);
      //let isolineObj = [isolineCenter, isolinePolygon];
      // Add the polygon and marker to the map:
      this.markerGroup.addObject(isolineCenter);
      this.polylineGroup.addObject(isolinePolygon);
    };

    let router = this.platform.getRoutingService();

    startLocs.forEach(loc => {

      let routingParams = {
        mode: 'fastest;car;traffic:enabled',
        start: `geo!${loc.geocode.lat},${loc.geocode.lng}`,
        range: this.maxTime * 60,
        rangetype: 'time',
        departure: queryDateString
      };
      // Call the Routing API to calculate an isoline:
      router.calculateIsoline(routingParams, onResult, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);            
      });
    });        
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('failed processing isochrones', err);
  }
  finally{
    this.isLoading = false;
  }
```

Comment: Here is the documentation link I mention:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/routing.html
Specifically:
"Note that the member elements of the routingParameters object literal directly map to the URL parameters required by the HERE Routing API. The parameter object can include any parameters recognized by the Routing API, offering complete flexibility in defining a route calculation request."

Comment: It would be interesting to see the HTTPRest request which is sent out. Can you please record it over a debugging tool? Another thing which comes into my mind is the area you are calculating the Isolines. Can you provide some examples too?

Comment: Here are two requests for the same lat/long
https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY&mode=fastest;car;&start=geo!53.4344811,-1.206727&range=1200&rangetype=time&departure=2019-01-22T08:00:00&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(18)

https://isoline.route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateisoline.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.0.17.0&app_id=XXX&app_code=YYY&mode=fastest;car;&start=geo!53.4344811,-1.206727&range=1200&rangetype=time&departure=2019-01-22T14:00:00&jsoncallback=H.service.jsonp.handleResponse(43)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode is missing the traffic part. Please try to add this '&mode=fastest;car;traffic:enabled'. Then you will also get for example you sent a different shape for e.g. 10:00 am.

Here we have some extended example for visualizing isolines:

https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/isoline_routing

This might be interesting for you too.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I've also refactored the code to be readable and to not instantiate a router on each start location.